# Hide A Class and Add Custom HTML Code Using Wordpress

Tags: php, customization, html

In my wordpress website I am trying to hide download button from non logged-in user and add a custom HTML to that section. My current code is hiding the download button but not displaying the text. I am a beginner PHP programmer so any help is really appreciated.

I am using this code:

```
<style>
<?php if(! is_user_logged_in() ) : ?>
    .product-purchase-box{
        display: none;
        $(".single-product-widget").text("Please Login/Register To Download");
    }
<?php endif; ?>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You mixed JavaScript code with css.

Going by the code you provided you would need to do this.

```php
<?php if (!is_user_logged_in()) : ?>
<style>
    .product-purchase-box{
        display: none;
    }
</style>
<script>
    ($ => {
        $(".single-product-widget").text("Please Login/Register To Download");
    })(jQuery);
</script>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: This is my target website: ezcliparts.com/downloads/geometric-hand-drawn-stylish-texture-pattern-abstract-seamless-background/

Comment: @KatherineElizabethKath I don't understand how this is relevant, could you explain? How is this link/comment relevant to your question or my answer?

Comment: Sorry for late replay. I tried the code on that provided link page. But it didn't had any reflection on the target element. May be the class I am targeting is wrong (I am trying to replace the "PURCHASE" text). Can you help me please

Comment: Seem to work fine. It hides the element with the class `.product-purchase-box` using the css and it changes that element inner content to `Please Login/Register To Download`. Here is the [console](https://prnt.sc/1s619y4) (google DevTools) of the element

Comment: I sent you the link to show the reflection of the change. There is nothing changed

Comment: If you got some time. May be the class is wrong. Can you please get the right class for me. I tried with a few but none of them working